# How to enable port 5000 on aws server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I checked all the questions that are related to allowing port on AWS EC2 and I have tried the following:

```bash
sudo ufw allow 5000

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

Also added the port to AWS SG as shown below

Outbound Configs
[image: AWS SG Outbound Config]

Inbound Configs
[image: AWS SG Inbound Config]

Still when I open my website it says:

> This site can’t be reached

Am I missing anything? Are above rules are correct and secure?

Comment: This are my ports, I could serve a nodejs app trougth port 5000 with this configurations[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eTyZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eTyZ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Inbound SG configs needs to be modified. As the image you have posted does not show that you allow `5000` in your AWS SG. So in this case you wont be able to access that port from outside unless you allow it in your security group that i assume it is attached already to your EC2 instance

Comment: Can you tell me what modification required?

Comment: Also check security group options.

Comment: AWS SecurityGroup > Inboud Rules > Add Custom TCP Port with value `5000` and the IP that you need to allow

Comment: @MostafaHussein: Thanks a lot, I added `Custom TCP Rule
TCP
5000
0.0.0.0/0` Are above secutiy group are safe from attacks?

Comment: From a security point of view you need to allow certain IPs only incase your application is not public yet. So maybe you can use the same IPs which you already use with SSH if you already using these IPs or maybe use a VPN with a specific IP